# future of backend web development vs front end web development

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jsp, web-deployment, frontend

I worked on C#, ASP.NET, JSP for couple of projects from 2009 - 2012. After that i was much more into Javascript, HTML, CSS, JQuery (Front end Development). So Now I am wondering is server side web technologies (ASP.NET, JSP, PHP) are dying ? The reason I asked this question is I can do fairly any kind of task in FrontEnd better than Server side technologies.

I seen soo many modern websites (Facebook, Google, Gmail... etc) was much more into FrontEnd development. so Now do I recall all my knowledge in server side web development or do I have to more focus on Front End development for the future web development ?

Any kind of comments are welcome

edit: is Node.js killing Java, C# ?

Comment: You can't store on a database on the server with just front-end, so no, of course back-end is not dying.  But as far as the UI, yes, the UI is now more done in Javascript that serverside languages.  But serverside is never going away.

Comment: I think if you can do something on the client side do it!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have front-end development without back-end development. Back-end development is certainly not dying.

That being said, some specific backend technologies might seem to be somewhat in decline, because newer, more hip technologies are becoming popular and replacing some of their market share (like Node.js instead of PHP and NoSQL databases instead of SQL databases).

The reason that any of these back-end technologies are "declining" is probably because there are simply more options when it comes to back-end tech. You can write server-side code in pretty much any language you want. But front-end technologies are pretty much limited to JavaScript and how the different browsers decide to support JavaScript.

--- Edit ---

Node.js is definitely growing massively in popularity right now. However, I wouldn't say that Node.js is killing Java or C# as back-end technologies. Java and C# still have very passionate supporters, and they are still used by a lot of programmers and companies around the world. And if nothing else, there will always be legacy code to worry about.